# Magnific Popup - Clear Image from cache

Tags: jquery, caching, magnific-popup

I use Magnific Popup for Image gallery.

In the gallery, I can adding or deleting images via ajax request.

The problem is by deleting the image, if I do that and open an image then Magnific Popup can´t find the file/image where recent is deleted and displayed an error.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to delete the file direct from cache?

[image: From chrome]

**I suppose that doesn't work.**

The second question is:

How can I reset Magnific Popup so that they don`t search the missing file?

I find this in [Magnific-popup Documentation](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html) to clear the cache but is not working for me:

`$.magnificPopup.instance.popupsCache = {};`

That`s my configuration:

```
$("#file").magnificPopup({
    type: "image",
    gallery:{
        enabled:true,
        arrows: false,
        preload: 0,
        navigateByImgClick: true    
    },
    showCloseBtn: false
});
```

Any help are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the easiest way to load a ressource without cache is to append a timestamp like so :
`file.jpg?t=123456`

About `magnificPopup`, i don't know this plug-in, but ; as i can read in documentation ; `popupsCache` option clear the cache for templates. But there's another option in api doc (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api) called `updateItemHTML()`, maybe you could give it a try ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for waste your time! :) +1 I found now the problem... That was my mistake. After success to delete the Image there was an `setTimeout` function for the result and so has Magnific popup enough time to load the old image file. Thanks again!